# Why does Winforms look and feel different on different Windows machines in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have been working on a simple Windows Forms application, the look and feel of the form in my VS 2022 and my monitor are different when the project is shared with a developer which he as well is using VS2022 on Windows 10.

It seems there is a lot of spacing between controls, and size of the form is different. This is at design time, and I am sure the application layout will differ as well when running!

Are there best practices for designing Winforms so the look and feel will stay the same across development and OS?

I have set `AutoScaleMode = none`

[image]

VS

[image]

Comment: Design at 100% scale (VS issues a warning when you don't), scale to Dpi and make your app DpiAware (`PerMonirV2` aware). You may be using .Net Framework, so set it in `App.config` (target .Net Framework 4.8). If it's .Net 6+, edit your Project's file (`Project -> Edit Project File`) and set `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` to the main `<PropertyGroup>`; this is going to affect the code that `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` generates

Comment: @Jimi thank you for the reply. My monitor now is set to 200% `Scale and layout`. `Display Resolution` is 3840 x 2160. The target Framework is `.Net 6`.  So I guess I have to redesign the Form now with 100% Scale. VS22 did not warn me of the scale, I used to see the warning in VS19.  It would be nice to conclude **best practices for designing Winforms** so the look and feel can be unified across development platforms and operating systems. Do I need as well to set each Form `AutoScaleMode = DPI` or `Font`